# change training data by traincascade to xml

Tags: opencv, training-data, haar-classifier

I use traincascade in opencv and i have output result of training like this

> result/
>
> params.xml
>
> stage0.xml
>
> stage1.xml
>
> stage2.xml
>
> stage3.xml
>
> stage4.xml
>
> stage5.xml

how can i change it to xml file

in haartraining i chnage the output result by

```
haarconv.exe data haarcascade.xml 24 24
```

and its change my data to xml

now i use traincascade how can i change it ?

> first image about haartraining output data
>
> and the second about traincascade data

also another question what the best haartraining or traincascade ?

[image: output of haartraining data]

[image: output of traincascade data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything.
Just wait for it to finish and it will make the cascade for you.